# SignalR - how to disable WebSockets (but keep other transports active)?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

In both a C# client and Web Client - how do I tell signalR - "Try everything **but** websockets"?

I have the following in my web code:

```
 window.hubReady = $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' });
```

But this is just javascript and longpolling; I'm looking for the configuration for both JS and C# clients to only remove websockets as a transport.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server:

```
 public class Startup    
 {
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
     {
         DisableWebSockets(GlobalHost.DependencyResolver);

         HubConfiguration hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
         hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
         app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
     }

     public static void DisableWebSockets(IDependencyResolver resolver)
     {
         var manager = resolver.Resolve<ITransportManager() as TransportManager;
         manager.Remove("webSockets");
     }
 }
```

On the client:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['serverSentEvents', 'foreverFrame', 'longPolling'] }).done(function () {...}
```

Edit - adding bracket

Comment: Wow!  How can I get in touch?  I see you do consulting and I'm interested in some paid assistance if you're open to it.

Comment: @SB2055 You can contact me via LinkedIn.

Comment: I don't have Premium (or your profile) - is there any other way?

Comment: I don't have premium either. If you go to my SO profile, you'll see a link to my LinkedIn page which includes contact info. I don't feel comfortable posting personal stuff here.

Comment: Typo; this:
`var manager = resolver.Resolve<ITransportManager()> as TransportManager;`
Should be
`var manager = resolver.Resolve<ITransportManager>() as TransportManager;`