# React SignalR - Do not send bearer token in URL

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, signalr

I am writing an application which has just failed pen testing for the following:

Authorisation Token is being sent in the URL:

```
 https://domain/Hub?access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Imh1Tjk1SXZQZmVocTM0R3pCRFoxR1hHaXJuTSIsImtpZCI6Imh1Tjk1SXZQZmVocTM0R3pCRFoxR1hHaXJuTSJ9.....
```

This is happening automatically when sending to the Hub which uses Azure AD authorisation.

```
    constructor (hub: string) {
    this.hubName = hub;
    this.hub = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Critical)
        .withUrl(`${this.hubURL}${hub}` , {
            skipNegotiation: true,
            transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
            accessTokenFactory: () => {
                return `${getToken()}`
            }
        })
        .build();
}
```

I've scoured for documentation, however I was wondering if there was a way to connect and send requests without exposing the bearer token within the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-3.1#access-token-logging)

> When using WebSockets or Server-Sent Events, the browser client sends
> the access token in the query string. Receiving the access token via
> query string is generally secure as using the standard Authorization
> header. Always use HTTPS to ensure a secure end-to-end connection
> between the client and the server. Many web servers log the URL for
> each request, including the query string. Logging the URLs may log the
> access token. ASP.NET Core logs the URL for each request by default,
> which will include the query string. For example:

And from this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1#bearer-token-authentication)

> In standard web APIs, bearer tokens are sent in an HTTP header.
> However, SignalR is unable to set these headers in browsers when using
> some transports. When using WebSockets and Server-Sent Events, the
> token is transmitted as a query string parameter.

Seems to me you could disable WebSockets and Server-Sent events. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738840/signalr-how-to-disable-websockets-but-keep-other-transports-active?rq=1) on how to remove WebSockets or Server-Sent events. But then you fallback to long polling or forever frame, and you may not want that.

Since your URL in your question is https I wouldn't bother that much if you have disabled the request logging.

Changing the log level for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` could be done in your `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```